# What value determines the current flowing between two interconnected ICs?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit

If I connect two ICs (lets say two Arduino UNOs with one pin configured as OUTPUT and another as INPUT), something must limit the current so that there is not a short circuit when driving HIGH.

What values on the datasheet should I be looking for? Some kind of internal pin resistance?

The reason I want to know is I want to put an LED inline to cause a 2V drop from a 5V IC to an ATTiny65 input pin but the LED forward current is limited to 20mA. (I realise there are better ways to do this but I have a PCB already printed off which only allows two 1206 components in series in the data line).

Comment: Why not use a voltage divider  (resistors) to convert 5 v to 3.3 v, since you are connecting to MCU pins (current in uA)

Comment: If you put a diode in the path, and there isn't a pulldown, how can you drive the input low again once you've driven it high? You'll be limited to reverse leakage current through the diode.

Answer (score 1):

The current is limited by the output impedance of the driver, and the input impedance of the receiver. A GPIO pin generally has very low output impedance in output mode (at most tens of ohms, likely less) and very high input impedance in input mode (millions of ohms), as long as the voltages remain between the voltage rails.

You shouldn't use an LED to reduce the voltage for level shifting because, aside from being a nasty hack, the LED's forward voltage depends on the current passing through it. Use a resistor divider instead.

Comment: Also look in the datasheet for these "electrical specifications." VOH/VOL = Typical volts output when low/high, VIL/VIH = Volts input to register as low/high, IOL/IOH = Source/sink current out/in as low/high, IIL/IIH = Leakage current input as low/high. Back in the days of 7400 and 4000-series discretes, it was necessary to analyse all of these currents. It was called "Fan-out" capability back then.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a requirement for only mounting in-series components.
If the input pin has built-in clamping diodes you might get away with only one series resistor.
You would have to properly size this resistor so the current does not exceed what the internal clamping diodes can handle.